# Intel injects itself in the environment with... magic

Tags: bash, qt, environment-variables, qt-creator, icc

I installed the Intel compiler to my Debian 8 WITHOUT root. So all the access the installer had was to my home directory. Now I open Qt Creator, and look into the environment of running my program, and I find intel compiler libraries in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other environment variables.

How could this happen?

Note that `~/.bashrc` wasn't modified.

Are there other places where environment variables can be modified?

Comment: Search your home directory for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, there are other files that can set environment variables.

Comment: @cnicutar OK, will do.

Comment: @cnicutar It's practically difficult to do this. There are thousands of results. The question is: What other files can modify environment variables in linux?

Comment: Thousands of files is peanuts for `grep`. That aside try a `find  / -name iccvars.sh`

Comment: @cnicutar I mean I have thousands of results and I can't analyze them all. That's impractical.

Comment: You installed the tools *how*? You opened QT Creator from where/how? There are thousands of results where (in the intel compiler installer sources)?

Comment: @EtanReisner Just a standard installation of Intel. I opened Qt Creator and loaded the project using with a CMake make file. The environment variables are visible in the project pane.

Comment: What is "a standard installation of Intel"? (I've never installed them.) How did you "open" QT Creator? Did you run the program from the shell where you had previously source the Intel tools script (`. install.sh`)? Does another user have the env vars set?